# i want to display the images according to the number selected from the select box in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Here I want to display the images according to the numbers selected from the select box and my values in select box are 9,12,18 and here is my code
my view page looks like this...

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/numberdisplay" id="numberdisplay" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 none-xs text-center">
    <div class="limiter hidden-xs">
      <label>Show</label>
      <select name="gallery" id="gallery">
        <option selected="selected" value="9">9</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="36">36</option>
      </select>
      per page
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //alert();
    $("#numberdisplay").change(function() {
      var parent = $(this).val();
      //alert(parent);

      var url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>roxcontrol/ajax_get_sub';
      $.post(url, {
          parent: parent
        }, function(data)

        {
          $('#gallery').html(data);
        });


    });

  });

</script>
```

My control page looks like this

```
public function ajax_get_sub()
  {
    $gal_id=$this->input->post('parent');
    $data['galery']=$this->roxmodel->get_gallery_by_number($gal_id);
    $this->load->view('ajax_get_sub',$data);
  }
```

My model page looks like this.

```
public function get_gallery_by_number($gal_id)
  {

      $this->db->order_by("gallery.id","desc");

  $query=$this->db->limit($gal_id)->get('gallery');
  return $query->result();
  }
```

Here I am not getting any images

Comment: if 9 display 9 images or corresponding image file (name 9)?

Comment: what does this means  $("#numberdisplay").change(function(){ ...

Comment: if 9 selected 9 images should be selected

Comment: How do we relate `9 => 0` ?

Comment: elaborate your concept and problem?

Comment: @safin chacko #numberdisplay is form id according to that id the image should   change i guess so

Comment: @rayon that was by mistake i type 0 now i have changed it

Comment: @gopal if 1 select "9" then 9 images should display and if 1 select "12" then 12 images should dispaly for that i guess we should have to use ajax so i had done like that and iam new in php

Comment: If you want to show first 9/12/24/36 images then just use limit in your sql query.

Comment: but if we give limit as 9 only once it will be coming then what about 12 and all iam selecting it by using select tag

Answer (score 0):

In controller Just get Post value from ajax call and try this

```
    public function ajax_get_sub() 
    {
    $gal_id=$this->input->post('gal_id');
    $this->db->order_by("id","desc");
    $query=$this->db->limit($gal_id)->get('gallery');
    $var="";
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
    $var .= "<img src=".$row->img_url."/> </br>"; //your table image url(path)
    }
    echo $var;
    }
```

In view File

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 none-xs text-center">
<div class="limiter hidden-xs">
  <label>Show :</label>
  <select name="gallery" id="gallery">
    <option selected="selected" value="9">9</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
  </select>
  per page
</div>
```

```
<div id="img_display">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#gallery").change(function() {
  var gal_id = $("#gallery").val();
  alert(gal_id);
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: base_url+'sample_controller/ajax_get_sub',
    cache: false,               
    data: {gal_id:gal_id},
    success: function(get_img){
        try{     
            $("#img_display").append(get_img);

    }catch(e) {     
        alert('Exception while request..'+JSON.stringify(e));
    }   

    },
    error: function(e){                     
        alert('Error while request..'+JSON.stringify(e));
    }
    });
  });
});
```

Dont forget to give value for gallery select option.
This is one of the way to append the element.

Comment: i had done like this but then also its not coming now what happen is if i select 9 all the values of the select box are disappearing

Comment: my ajax_get_sub page looks like this

Comment: <select name="gallery" id="gallery" class="form-control">
 <?php foreach ($galery as $row) {?>
 <option value=""><?php echo $row->image; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
</select

Comment: are you sure to display  success data in html.  because you are using $('#gallery').html(data); but id gallery is select tag. And sure it will work everytime onchanges in select tag

Comment: there iam having doubt

Comment: can you suggest me any solution

Comment: i have got it...i changed my code a little bit and atlast i found it out thanks to everyone for helping